# Classification of isolated singularity /Laurent series

Tags: laurent-series, singularity

I want to find out, what kind of singularties does

$ f(z)= \frac{1}{z^3-z^5}$ have.

I would do the following steps:
$ f(z)= \frac{1}{z^3-z^5} = \frac{1}{z^3(1-z)(1+z)}$ so I have $ z_1=1, z_2=-1 , z_3=0$
I can argue by the limit test, that $ z_i$ are poles.
For example $ \lim_{z\rightarrow 1} (1-z)f(z)=  \lim_{z\rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{z^3(1+z)}= \frac{1}{2} \ne 0 $

Am I right?

How can I find the Laurent series of f  and classify the singularties without using the Limit test.

Comment: "The Laurent sieres"...there are many: about what point?

Comment: That's the point. There is  no explicit point or can i take  the difference between singularities as radius of convergence? How would you classify the singularities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: they are all poles.

Now, consider the point $0$. Since$$f(z)=\frac1{z^3}\times\frac1{1-z^2}$$and since, near $0$, you have$$\frac1{1-z^2}=1+z^2+z^4+z^6+\cdots$$then (again, near $0$) you have$$f(z)=\frac1{z^3}+\frac1z+z+z^3+\cdots$$and this confirms that $0$ is a pole.

You can do a similar thing at $\pm1$.

Comment: Thank you:) How do I ge the Laurent series for 1. I don't see how I can do that?

Comment: This one is more complex, but you have$$\frac1{-z^3-z^4}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{7 (z-1)}{4}-\frac{31}{8}(z-1)^2+\cdots$$and therefore$$f(z)=\frac1{z-1}\times\frac1{-z^3-z^4}=-\frac{1}{2(z-1)}+\frac74-\frac{31}8(z-1)+\cdots$$

Comment: How do you get the series for $\frac{1}{-z^3-z^4}$?

Comment: I just computed the first $3$ terms of its Taylor series.

Comment: I see:) For the singularity at $ z=-1$ you do the same thing, but you factor $ z+1$ out.

Comment: That's exactly right!

Comment: I have another example. $f(z)=\frac{sin (2z)}{(z-1)^3}$. I can compute the taylor-series of sin(2z), but i can't get this series together with $(z-1)^3$. What's the Tck?

Comment: That's another question. Please post it as such.

Comment: Ok i will do that. Thank you for you help:)